# Android Studio Update setDependencyCacheDir error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

How can I resolve this error :

Android Studio : 3.1.4
Gradle version : 4.4
Android Plugin Version : 3.1.4

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'myApplication'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir(Ljava/io/File;)
```

Can I use Old Gradle(4.4) and Android Plugin version(2.14.1) with new Android Studio (3.1.4) as my current project is using this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting build folder in root and project repo, Also try removing gradle cache folder may be it helps. usually it happens because there are some corrupt files in root folder

Comment: this worked along with the path to the root directory of the project  is shortened

Answer (score 0):

Update the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

and Root Project Dependencies

```
 dependencies {
        //Gradle dependencies 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // Kotlin if use kotlin your project
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Comment: you might use in your project so just added